# How to remove this duplicate else statement?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

Here is the pseudocode:

```
if A
  then B
  if C
    then D
  else
    then E
else 
  then E
```

B, D, E includes several lines. We can see the "else" here repeated twice. How to remove the duplicate code and maintain the function？Do not use "goto".

Comment: I think you've got a couple of extra `then`s. (Yeah, I'm complaining about the syntax of pseudocode.)

Answer (score 1):

Just make them a function. i.e.

```
void E() {

... Your several lines of code here

}
```

Comment: How does this help to avoid the second/first else?

Answer (score 1):

```
if A
  then B
  if C
    then D
if not (A and C)
  then E
```

or

```
if A
  then B
if (A and C)
  then D
else
  then E
```

Answer (score 1):

As Ed Heal suggested, just make a function.

Sometimes this isn't practical because of a large number of variables that need to be passed, and the fact that you really only need to call it from two places.

In that case, you set a flag:

```
needE = 1

if A {
  B
  if C {
    D
    needE = 0
  }
}

if needE {
  E
}
```

This might be preferable to other solutions that repeat the logic later, because sometimes your logic has side-effects.  You can of course compute the logic once and store the result, but that means even more variables.

Comment: - Just put all the variables into a structure.

Comment: Are you suggesting that would make for simpler code than setting a flag?

Comment: I like this method, it removes the duplicated codes and is simple.

Answer (score 1):

Using boolean logic, here is one way to do it:

```
if A
  then B
if A and C
  then D
if !A or !C
  then E
```

Comment: I think this method has judged A 3 times.

Comment: Only if the value isn't cached. You'll have to check A at least twice (as shown in another answer). Which is more clear depends on the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

What about a "hidden goto"? This way you at least get the fewest necessary boolean evaluations:

```
do
{
  if (A)
  {
    B;

    if (C)
    {
      D;

      break;
    }
  }

  E;
} while (0);
```